# Sending data message to iOS device results in FirebaseMessagingException: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

When we are sending a FCM data message with the Firebase Admin SDK to an iOS device we are getting the following exception.

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

We are using `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0` and the message is build like this.

```
Message.builder()
        .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
            .putHeader("apns-priority", "10")
            .setAps(Aps.builder()
                .setContentAvailable(true)
                .build())
            .build())
        .putAllData(data)
        .setToken(token)
        .build();
```

I don't think that there is something wrong with the token itself, because sending a push notification to this token works.

Also the message size shouldn't be an issue, because it is basically just an id in it.

I'm not sure if it happens on all iOS devices.
Am i missing something on building the data message?

**Update**

I checked the details included at the exception and there it looks like something is wrong with the token.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "message.token",
            "description": "Invalid registration token"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when i send a data message to the same token using postman, there is no error and the response looks like this.

```
{
"multicast_id": 7455611938954436367,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
        "message_id": "0:1614145427166557%c5757de0f9fd7ecd"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Check the other details included in the exception (especially the HTTP response payload from FCM). That should provide some hints about what's going on.

Comment: I updated my question with more information. Is there a way at firebase to look at logs or something to better understand what is happening with this messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out.

My problem was that i was setting the `apns-priority` to "10". According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html), notifications with a priority of "10" have to be delivered immediatly.

If i put my device into flight mode for example, and sending my data push it failes with the mentioned firebase exception about an invalid token. Which is very missleading in my opinion.

If i set the `apns-priority` to "5" everything works fine.

Comment: Does this mean that using the default notification instead of data is better when setting APNS priority to 10?

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you try to use a push notification with only data (silent push notification) which do not required the user to have granted permission to receive on iOS, but you set some iOS specific parameters in the request.

In this case, the error does not occur if the user has granted permission to receive push notifications or you don't specify any iOS specific parameter.

Comment: Can you cite a documentation about this silent push notification when using data message on iOS? Thanks!